# Hidden "alert" divs when no content

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Content into alert divs is coming through PHP variables, but divs are visible even if the PHP variables are empty.

```
<span class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo  $sentFailed  ?></span>
<span class="alert alert-success"><?php echo  $sentSuccess ?></span>
```

Right now it looks like: [image]

How can I make divs visible only when there is something in set in PHP variables.

I have tried:

```
 <span class="alert alert-danger"><?php   if(!empty($sentFailed)){echo $sentFailed;}   ?></span>
 <span class="alert alert-success"><?php  if(!empty($sentSuccess)){echo $sentSuccess;}  ?></span>
```

I am looking for bootstrap, jquery or php solution primarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
<?php  
if(!empty($sentFailed)){    
?>
 <span class="alert alert-danger"><?php   echo $sentFailed;   ?></span>
<?php
}
?>
```

It means if PHP variable has no value then Dont show html tags ,and Variable value ,

Else show both.